# hiding parent div and child div using PHP?

Tags: php, css, html

```
<div class="main"><div class="sub">
<div class="content">

some content


</div></div></div>
```

above is a sample div

```
$data = "some value";

  if(!empty($data)){ show div(the above one)}else{ hide dive}
```

how do I show or hide div

I want to separate HTML from PHP so later design or modification of layout and HTML page is easy.

Comment: The question does not make any sense. What do you mean by show or hide? Is the intention to not output html for the div if some condition is met?

Comment: if $data variable is empty then hide entire div otherwise display. my question is without echo the entire div from PHP I want to separate HTML and PHP. the one option is to use javascript. but I was looking for other options. why I want to separate PHP from HTML is if you load this file into adobe dream weaver the entire layout look wiered. and if some one doesn't have knowledge in php cant edit the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to make a CSS class called hidden like this

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Then you can add/remove it through php like this:

```
$divClass = '';
if (!empty($data)) $divClass = 'hidden';
```

Then, you HTML would look like this

```
<div class="content <?php echo $divClass; ?>"></div>
```

Comment: yes I think this works ...so if $data variable is empty then the entire dive wont display right?? but what about child div within the main div??

Answer (score 0):

you can just use CSS style property `display:none` to hide it or just don't send it to the user from you PHP code on false condition.

```
$data = "some value";
if (!empty($data)) {
  echo "<div><div><div>$data</div></div></div>";
  }
else {
  // do nothing 
  // or echo "<div><div><div style="display:none">$data</div></div></div>"; 
  }
```

Comment: but this one really ruin webpage

Comment: I mean the designer cant edit the layout if any modification required right?? otherwise he need to know PHP.

Comment: Got you, you want to make change to display setting of DIV using PHP but also to keep HTML code unchanged as much as possible, right?

Comment: I was using this PHP echo solution but I want HTML separate from PHP I wont say 100% but almost. that's why I raised a query here

Comment: So you can use @Mybbor's solution, looks nice, but keep in mind, last line is not pure HTML (it's in fact also PHP script).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the result of your check to a Javascript function and use that to assign CSS to hide it on load.